# Bash - how to set variable within an if [] condition and use outside

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get my head around this. I have a basic Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_exit=0

while [ "$do_exit" == 0 ] ; do

        echo $do_exit

        do_exit=1

done
```

This works. However, when I want to set `do_exit=1` inside an `if` condition:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_exit=0

while [ "$do_exit" == 0 ] ; do

    free=`free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}'`

    if [ "$free" -gt 0 ]
    then

        echo $do_exit

        do_exit=1

    fi & sleep 5;

done
```

`$do_exit` is ALWAYS 0 ... so never exists. What am I doing wrong? I'm have the same issue with "breaking" and "exit 0" when I want to kill te script - it just carries on!)

I must be misunderstanding how variables work in Bash? In Perl (my normal programing language), you can set variables anywhere (with the exception of explicitly setting them in a function)

Comment: what is the value of `free`? are you sure it's getting set to something `-gt 0`?  is the `echo` firing?  `& sleep 5` should probably be `&& sleep 5` ... but I'm also wondering about the placement of this clause (ie, when exactly do you want the script to `sleep`?); as alluded to in Bayou's answer ... a single `&` says to spawn a sub-process and put said process in the background in which case the assignment (performed in a sub-process) is not seen by the parent process

Comment: FYI, `[` is not part of `if` syntax. It's just one of the infinite number of commands you can use _anywhere_, including in an `if`, but you can use `if` without it; for example, `if grep -qe pattern file; then...`

Comment: Also, the only standard comparison operator inside `[` is `=`, not `==`. In some shells, using `==` will cause an error.

Comment: Anyhow -- the two duplicates this is closed with explain why using `&` causes the assignment to be ineffective.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks The `if []` statement was just an example `free=free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}` works as expected (it holds the amount of ram available as an int). It seems like the issue was the & where it was spawning a sub-process. I didn't realise that was the behaviour.

Comment: Eh? Your `free=free -m | grep Mem | awk 'print $4` code sample certainly does not work as expected; it doesn't even run `free` at all (it tries to run a command named `-m`, and then presumably fails because that command doesn't exist), nor does it persistently assign to a variable named `free` (as the variable `free` is given the value `free` only for the duration of that immediately-failing `-m` command). Now, if what you _meant_ was `free=$(free -m | awk '/Mem/ { print $4 }')`, then yes, that certainly works; but you need a command substitution on the right-hand side of your assignment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thats because I had to remove the backticks from it, otherwise SO got confused with the code format ;)

Comment: @AndrewNewby, you can use triple-backticks to make single-backticks work in SO, though it's _always_ better to use the POSIX-specified `$(...)` syntax instead; the standard-compliant syntax is easier to nest, doesn't make surprising changes to how backslashes behave within them, etc. -- and the POSIX sh standard has been out since 1992, so you don't need to worry about finding modern shells that don't support it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy haha I'm used to using backticks in Perl code =) (only really dabble in bash for the very rare job like this). I'll remember that for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of errors.

1. you echo do_exit *before* you set it to 1
2. you have `fi & sleep 5;` which makes the if statement a child process, thus you can't use the value in the parent process
3. `-gt` is for numeric comparisment, not strings.

Below should work for you.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

do_exit=0

while [ "$do_exit" == 0 ] ; do

    free=`free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}'`

    if [[ $free -gt 0 ]]; then
        do_exit=1
        echo ${$do_exit}
    fi
    sleep 5;

done
```

You can `break` while loops as well. Check this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

    free=$(free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}')

    if [[ $free -gt 0 ]]; then
        break;
    fi
    sleep 5;
done
```

Comment: Ahhh man that was it! So the problem turned out to be I was doing:  `fi & sleep 5;` instead of `fi`, and then `sleep 5` on another line! (that was some code I found online that seemed to work - I didn't realise it would cause complications later! Thanks for the explanation